# Find shortest path in 2D weighted grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have a 2D grid, somtehing like this, but a little bit bigger

```
A 1 2 2 2
2 1 X 2 1
1 X X 1 2
1 2 X 1 1
2 2 1 B 2
```

I want to find the shortest path from A to B. Where is X, there is not possible to go. From 1 to 2 is cost 2, from 2 to 1 is cost 1. I can move horizontally and vertically.

I imagined it like graph with evaluated vertexes and then I tried transform it to graph with evaluated edges. Then i wanted to apply dijkstra algorithm on it. In one article I read, that it is possible to apply dijkstra directly to grid.

My question is if it is possible to apply dijkstra algorithm directly to weighted grid? If no, how can I make a graph from grid or adjacency matrix? But adjacency matrix is probably too large for my inputs.

Thank you very much for your answers :)

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between weighted grid and a weighted graph for the algorithm. On every iteration you should fetch all possible next steps and pick the one that will give the cheapest total weight of the path. Why can't you fetch the weight of any step from your grid?

Comment: Sorry, but I cant understand your question, because of my english :/ I look for an algorihm, that finds the shortest path on a grid. The weighted grid is something like graph with evaluated vertexes. I prefer to use dijktra and dijkstra can works with graph with evaluated edges.

Comment: It is possible to apply dijkstra to your grid. The grid is the same as graph. You have weights in your grid. You should modify your algorithm to get the weight of the step from the grid, not from a graph.

Comment: Please, could you show me some code or pseudocode to do that ? I know make values for egdes only on the paper. I cant code it. I am just starting programmer :)